# Adding notes or descriptions to breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently debugging a Java application and often find myself wondering why I inserted a breakpoint at a particular location.

I was wondering if it's possible to add a note or description to my breakpoints in the Eclipse debugging view?

I can't find a setting in Eclipse or a suitable plug-in, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: How will it help you ?

Comment: I'm new to this project and when debugging it's easier to toggle the breakpoints on and off if they are called a friendly name like "Send request", rather than the class name & line number, etc.

Comment: I can see this has been downvoted, would be nice to know why? Is this bad practice? Is this not a suitable question? Is this not an elegant solution to the problem? Although, my question wasn't why I wanted this, it was if it can be done.

Comment: Upvoted. @Geditdk has valid point here. I also advise @aphex solution for time being. One more point: You can change the breakpoints view layouts. Open breakpoints view(`Windows > Show View > Breakpoints`). Click view menu item(Small downward triangle) select Group by option. Choose the option you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to describe breakpoints. Here is a workaround that you can use.

You could use tasks in order to describe your breakpoints. Right click on the line bar --> Add `Task`. In the description you can add whatever you want. Then add also a breakpoint on the same line.

In order to see the tasks, open the view Tasks from

> Windows --> Show View --> Other -->Tasks

Comment: I guess if there is no other way this is the easiest solution.